# Как правильно парсить html страницу

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-berlin

На сайте есть некий список наименований с ссылками. Мне нужно получить данные с названием класса `<ul class="modelsList"> <li>` ... То есть мне нужно запарсить html страницу. Использую следующий пример:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  idoc: IHTMLDocument2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  V: OleVariant;
  HTML: String;
begin
  //Загрузка страницы в htmldoc
  idhttp1.HandleRedirects:=true;
  //html:=idhttp1.Get('нужный сайт');

  v:=VarArrayCreate([0,0],VarVariant);
  v[0]:= HTML;
  idoc:=coHTMLDocument.Create as IHTMLDocument2;
  idoc.write(PSafeArray(System.TVarData(v).VArray));
  //загрузили в htmldoc
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
  Element: mshtml.IHTMLElement;
begin
  memo1.Lines.Clear;
  for i := 0 to idoc.all.length-1 do
  begin
    element:=idoc.all.item(i,0) as IHTMLElement;

    //здесь выдает ошибку [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(96): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'className'

    if Element.className='modelsList' then
    begin
      memo1.Lines.Add(element.outerHTML);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Выдает ошибку (отмечено в коде):

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(96): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'className'

Как решить проблему или как правильно парсить web страницы?

Comment: Вопросы: Что значит парсить в вашем понимании? Что конкретно и как вы хотите отпарсить? Какова конечная цель?

Comment: На сайте есть некий список наименований с ссылками, мне нужно получить их получить. Мне нужно получить данные с названием класса <ul class="modelsList"> <li>...

Comment: я для парсинга использую php библиотеку Simple_html_dom. Небольшой мануал по ней.
https://xdan.ru/uchimsya-parsit-saity-s-bibliotekoi-php-simple-html-dom-parser.html

Comment: Откуда вы взяли `className`? В интерфейсе `IHTMLElement` есть такой метод/свойство?

Comment: Воспользовался примером http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi/thread586340.html

Answer (score 1):

Если открыть объявление интерфейса `IHTMLElement` в модуле `MSHTML`, то можно легко заметить, что нужное вам свойство называется `_className`. Это связано с тем, что в базовом классе `TObject`, от которого наследуются все классы в Delphi (даже если это явно не указано), есть метод `ClassName`, который возвращает имя класса объекта Delphi.

Поменяйте свой код вот так:

```
if Element._className = 'modelsList' then
```

Comment: Пробовал, возвращает null

Comment: Это свойство типа `WideString`, там не может быть `null`. Что возвращает `null`?

Comment: Прошу извинения, пустую строку

Comment: Видимо, это от того, что у этого конкретного элемента нет класса? Как писали на английском SO, самый правильный способ, это парсить html с помощью `MSXML` и для поиска нужных элементов пользоваться запросами `XPath`.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду пробовать